# Which topics in maths should I know before I dive into programming for image processing?

Tags: self-learning, education, signal-processing, image-processing

I am a student who wants to start out with programming for Image processing but as I do not have a good mathematical background(I haven't studied A-level Maths) I would like to know what are the mathematical topics I should have a good grasp on before starting programming for image processing?Please also tell the order in which I should study them.Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this question is relevant here. However, a good course on optimization (linear & non-linear, in addition convex) would be a good one.

Comment: College algebra.

Comment: Linear algebra plays a big role in both fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Algebra**: matrix calculations, optimizations and etc

**Basic Signal Processing** (such as Oppenheim's textbook): sampling theorem, discrete signals, Fourier transform, z-transform, filtering, wavelet filter and etc

**Image Processing** (Such as Gonzales's textbook): de-noising, image enhancement, image filtering and etc

Comment: Is Calculus also needed or am I good without it?